# Registering nodes with chef-validator

Tags: chef-infra

I am attempting to write a PowerShell chef-client for Windows.  I have got quite a long way with it using the documentation on the Opscode Docs site.

However I am having problems registering a new node with Chef using the 'chef-validator' key.

I know that the signature I have created is correct as I can substitute my name and key and I can successfully create a new client and get the private key in the response.  However when I use the chef-validator my Chef server throws an HTTP 500 error :-(.

I am using Chef 11.0.8.  I have been unable to work out where there might be some logs from Chef on the server that might show what the error is.

If anyone has any pointers on this I would be most grateful.

Thanks, Russell

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, this is working.

I think the Chef server was doing some clean up work after I had deleted an old client and then I was recreating the same one.  After sometime the chef-validator was able to craete the new client.